# What may cause the screen to turns off after few minutes without option to turn it on again

Tags: fedora, power-management, screensaver

I've just installed Fedora 29 XFce on Dell laptop (Inspiron 15) and it turn off after few minutes, moving a mouse o pressing any key don't turn it on. To turn it on I've needed to hold down power button to shut it down and then turn it on again.

The computer is turn on because I have a LED in my external USB HDD and it's on.

Anybody what option may be responsible for this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I think it was hibernation option in System tab for AC power and disabled power button in Generic (first) Tab in power management.